# Previous day function

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Is there a function for previous day in discoverer/oracle? I need to run a daily report for data through the previous day. I was hoping there is a formula using system date -1, but I haven't been able to find anything to help.

Comment: Are you sure you that you don't want the [previous week/business day](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:906593600346091624)?

Answer (score 1):

You are very close

```
select trunc(sysdate) -1 yesterday
from dual
```

trunc() strips out the time portion.  You could also put the -1 inside the brackets if you want.  The results will be the same.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, This is the answer. [It works perfectly](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8)